# Getting filename from $_FILES in Yii Framework

Tags: php, file-upload, yii

I am trying to get filename and temp path from $_FILES array in controller class,
I am using $_FILES['image'] to get filename in controller class but it prints empty.
but when i print the whole $_FILES using var_dump it prints the filename, temp path.

MY Controller Code,

```
public function actionUpload()
{
        $model=new UploadModel();
        echo var_dump($_FILES);
        echo "image-->".$_FILES['image'];

}
```

My Model code,

```
<?php
class UploadModel extends CFormModel 
{
  public $image;
    // ... other attributes

    public function rules()
    {
              return array(
                'image','file',
                        'safe'=>true,
                        'allowEmpty'=>TRUE,
                        'maxSize'=>512000,
                        'types'=>'csv',
                        'tooLarge'=>'The size of the file is more than 100Kb',
                        'wrongType'=>'the file must be in the jpeg,png format',
            );
    }
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'image'=>'image',
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why no to do this in **Yii STYLE** only

```
    public function actionUpload()
    {
            $model=new UploadModel();
    //rest of your code

            $model->image=  CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
            if(!empty($model->image))
            {
                echo $model->image->name . $model->image->size;
            }

//render view here
    }
```

In **rules**

```
'tooLarge'=>'The size of the file is more than 250Kb',
'wrongType'=>'the file must be in the csv format',
```

AND if the case is such that you do want to do in  the **Yii style** then 
**Use this**

```
echo "image-->".$_FILES['image']['name'];
```

Comment: Yes i got filename , how to get the File Path ?

Comment: why do you want to get the path when you have uploaded the image?

Answer (score 0):

Use the UploadedFile Module
it has several attributes

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            // get instances of uploaded files
            $model->english_file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'english_file');
            $model->english_file->saveAs('uploads/' . $model->english_file->name);
}
```

for more info;
[Yii2 UploadedFile](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile#$name-detail)